# Where should I write "equally" in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

Where Should I write the word "equally" in this sentence in order to show that the number of tasks on all devices is the same?

> Results indicate that this approach distributes tasks between devices.

Should it be like this:

> Results indicate that this approach distributes tasks **equally** between devices.

Comment: Yes, what you have is correct

Answer (score 1):

I think it sounds fine as written. However, to be even clearer and to remove any ambiguity, I'd recommend the following:

> Results indicate that this approach **equally** distributes tasks between devices.

Answer (score 0):

Including 'equally' is more precise, and likely better.

'Distribution' does not have the connotation of distributing equally. For example, "Robin Hood takes from the rich and distributes to the poor." There is no sense that each poor person will receive a similar payout.

Without the word 'equally,' it could be that the approach distributes tasks on a weighted basis. Or that random chance means that distribution will not be equal.